# Inverse Mercator projection from plane to sphere

Tags: geographics, textures

I made a Mercator map of the Earth like this:

```
 mymap = GeoGraphics[GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], 
  GeoProjection -> "Mercator", GeoGridLines -> 10, 
  GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin], GeoModel -> 1]
```

Now I try to texture the sphere with it using the following code:

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> None, 
 MeshStyle -> None, Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
 PlotPoints -> 200, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[mymap]], Axes -> False,
 Boxed -> False,
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> False, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5/(2*Pi), -#4/Pi} &)]
```

This results in something looking like this.

[image: textured sphere]

What I would like to do next is to make this projection an inverse Mercator projection so that the rectangles formed by the longitudinal and latitudinal lines in the image become squares. If I understand this correctly, it is only necessary to adapt the `-#4/Pi`-term in the `TextureCoordinateFunction`. However, I am not able to find the transformation. Neither the Gudermannian function (`-Gudermannian[#4/Pi]`) nor the inverse Gudermannian function (`-Log[Tan[#4/Pi]]`) give the right result.

Does anyone know where I make a mistake? Do I misunderstand the Mercator projection itself or its implementation in Mathematica? Or do I use `TextureCoordinateFunction` incorrectly?

Any comments are highly appreciated!

Update: I have come across the problem again and still, after hours, am not able to see where I go wrong. The problem lies in the scaling of the texture in North-South direction, i.e. the latitudal lines (corresponding to the "y-direction" `-#4/Pi` coming from the Texture 'mymap' are incorrect.
Does anyone have some idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try    TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5/(2 Pi), (Pi - InverseGudermannian[#4 - Pi/2])/(2 Pi)} &)

Comment: The Mercator map is incomplete, only reaching latitudes approximately up to +-85 degrees. Therefore the SphericalPlot3D result has two holes near the poles. If you used a map with the "Equirectangular" projection then it would just be TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5/(2 Pi), -#4/Pi} &)